# Fail to install Tensorflow lite dependencies on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pip, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying the Tensorflow official tutorial to deploy object detection on Raspberry Pi4B.

Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi

However, the error happens on this line.

```
# The script install the required dependencies and download the TFLite models.
sh setup.sh
```

When executing, the dependencies installation get stuck on installing build denpendencies.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/liu/Tensor/tensor_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (24.0)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting argparse (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/argparse/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.0 in /home/liu/Tensor/tensor_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.26.4)
Collecting opencv-python~=4.5.3.56 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached opencv-python-4.5.3.56.tar.gz (89.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... /
```

And after it get stuck for two or three minutes, the error appears (The error is quite long, below just the end of it).

```
            error: Command "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_CBLAS -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=-1 -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/home/liu/Tensor/tensor_venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.11/build/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.11/build/src.linux-aarch64-3.11/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d -std=c99" failed with exit status 1
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
See above for output.
```

It seems that some problems happens on `numpy` or `gcc`. And I tried other tutorial, but all have the same error.